# Autonumber column in dataverse, without typing prefixed string when searching

Tags: powerapps, dataverse

Hi I have a Autonumber column(StudentID) in dataverse with the prefixed string "S", when new records created, the column's value is change to :

```
S-0001
S-0002
S-0003
```

I create a power app, and I need a search function for the StudentID column, but each time when we do the searching, we need type "S-", how can we aviod this? see just want to type the number: 0001,0002,0003